# While installing firebase on my system I'm facing this error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, npm-install, npm-package

[While running npm install --save react-firebase
I'm facing above error I tried to read the logs but it wasn't help at all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MzHO.png)

I want to install Firebase successfully on my system. It is showing could not resolve dependency error along with the --location==global and many other. You can refer to the screenshot.

Comment: Going forward, please don't post screenshots of textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 1):

The right way to install Firebase on your system is to add Firebase-cli using `npm install -g firebase-tools`.

You can use this [Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) for guidance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help,

it says [here](https://github.com/unfold/react-firebase) that React Firebase in not maintained anymore,

but i think you can install [firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) directly into your react project.

Comment: Then we to have externally add the FIREBASE dependency in package.json? Because I have installed it through cmd but to import it in my project it should be added in dependency? Right

Comment: @PradeepSharma, i think when installing a dependency it will be automatically added to your package.json. then you can import `initializeApp` from `firebase/app`. are you using npm ?